# Как нажать на ссылку через querySelector?

Tags: javascript, html

Как найти эту ссылку через `document.querySelector`? id тут нет, а элементов с одинаковыми классами - много. Возможно ли как то делать по href? Или, полагаю, искать нужно по тому, что написано в `path d`, но как?

В общем, научите пожалуйста)

(Нажмите для увеличения)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Очень плохой вопрос. Приведите html текстом. Какие отличительные свойства у этой ссылки? Зачем Вы называете ее кнопкой?

Comment: @Igor, а как приложить столько html кода, что бы по уровням (веткам) было?

Comment: Скопируйте столько html-a, сколько Вам надо, из "Инструментов Разработчика", а потом вырежите оттуда все, что считаете лишним, в любом редакторе.

Comment: @Igor, да, но тогда ведь он будет кашей, одной длинной строкой.

Comment: Вы уже пробовали?

Comment: @Igor, Да. Либо я чего то не понимаю (а не понимаю я многого), либо же, скриншот - лучший вариант предоставления html кода, сразу видны все ветки.

Comment: Я сделал то, что описал выше с Вашим комментарием - в ответе ниже. Никакого дополнительного форматирования не понадобилось.

Comment: @Igor, А почему у меня тогда выходит каша одной строкой...

Comment: Потому что Вы делаете не то, что я написал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Если ссылок с такими же классами и `href` адресом больше нет, можете использовать
  `document.querySelector('a.link-subtle.main-navBar-navBarLink[href="/lyrics-plus"]')`
  Объснение: здесь мы выбираем тег `<a>`, у которого есть аттрибут `href="/lyrics-plus"` и классы `link-subtle`, `main-navBar-navBarLink`
- Если такой элемент не единственный, можете использовать `document.querySelector('.main-navBar-entryPoints a.link-subtle.main-navBar-navBarLink:nth-child(4)` здесь мы выбираем все теги `<a>` навбара и из них выбираем четвертый с помощью псевдокласса `:nth-child(4)`

Совет на будущее: HTML лучше вставлять кодом, т.к. на скриншотах не всегда легко разобрать текст и какие-то элементы приходится переписывать.